# Enough about bits, bytes in book language. I want to know what a bit is in general. Electricity?

Tags: bit-rate, gigabit

It has been 4 years I am familiar with bits, bytes and true false, on off situation. What are bits in general? Are they electricity? When we say bits per second, are we talking about the speed of electricity? What are they? Who are they?

Comment: It's a state of the mind. Yours, to begin with, and of the circuit that is storing it. (In the form of voltage, current, charge, or magnetic flux)

Comment: Why I get a downvote for asking a question?

Comment: Thank you Sredni

Comment: @Obiick if I had to take a guess, because you used a click-baity title and have not researched your question well. You *know* that a bit is a binary digit, that's it. And the topic "speed of electricity" could have very well been researched on here, as well!

Comment: I was just confused about difference between bits and electricity. people talk about speed of bits and speed of electricity. But I never seen bits but electricity.

Comment: when it is "on" state, the device is receiving information, data or signals. right? if so is not it electricity who is sending? when it is "off" state, nothing send. right?

Comment: no, not right. As every single answer here has told you. It helps if you read them with an open mind without the prejudices that the wording of your question suggests you have.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lack of research.

Answer (score 9):

A bit is just a unit of information.

What makes a bit a bit is that a human decided that there was a threshold somewhere, and everything below the threshold is zero, everything above the threshold is 1.

Besides that it can be physically encoded with anything: voltage, current, charge on a capacitor, ink on paper, length of a hole on a compact disc, position of an object, etc. For example, this is a bit:

[image]

([pic source](https://www.amazon.fr/Anley-Remplacement-Transporteur-davertissement-Plastique/dp/B09J4L59LR/ref=asc_df_B09J4L59LR/?tag=googshopfr-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=554587087350&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17594526635689314570&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9056028&hvtargid=pla-1532145328035&th=1)) and this bit seems to be active-high.

Comment: is there any way to see bits ? what is the difference then?

Comment: Well we can't see voltage, but you can display a bit using a LED

Comment: @Obiick It is like asking if there is a way to see numbers. Sure, many. You could write them down. Or you could put that many balls in a cup. Or you could make a bar graph in Excel. But you cannot actually see the numbers. You can only see the ink on the paper, or the balls in the cup, or the graph on the screen.

Comment: Such a shame the question was closed. This picture is worth a kilobit.

Comment: And "active high"! It wasn't lost on me. Beautiful.

Answer (score 6):

In general, "bit" is a short for "**b**inary dig**it**". That is, it is an abstract term, just a name of the symbols used in binary notation.

In a less general scope, bits are units of information. When you answer a question with "yes" or "no", you provide a single bit of information. Sometimes less than that though, if the information is redundant.

The term by itself is totally unrelated to electricity, but since our electronics work naturally with binary data, this data is most naturally is quantified with binary digits (bits).

You can use means other than electricity to transmit bits. The aforementioned "Yes/No" words, light pulses, smoke signaling and what not. When we say "bits per second" we only refer to how many times a bit can be signaled by any of these per second.

Comment: is not signal is also electricity? How we are transferring bits then? How they are being send?

Comment: What do you mean by "not signal"? As I said, bits can be transmitted by many means unrelated to electricity. If you have a flashlight (or a candle, if we want to get away from electricity completely), you can define that the "on" state would signify the `1` bit and "off" will be  `0`  (or vice versa, it is really just a matter of convention). Or you can tell than waving the flashlight to the right will be `1` and to the left - `0`. Now you can take your flashlight and start transmitting. Your friend familiar with your encoding will be able to receive it and decode, if he can see your signals.

Comment: Note, that the rate you are able to wave your flashlight is not related to the speed of light.

Comment: So when I am turning on my flashlight, "on" state, I am sending signal to my friend. What is that signal here? for our example it is light. But for bits is it electricity?

Answer (score 4):

A bit is a signalling format that has two states. Really that is all it is. In a sense there is no connection to the physical world. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) explains it quite well along with some history.

The article says that it originally occurred in Bell Labs as a contraction of "binary digit". Once identified as a data element, then anything that has two states can be used to represent it.

Bits per second is the rate that data can be transferred from one place to another "one bit at a time". There is not really a "speed of electricity". The data rate is determined by the capabilities of the receivers and transmitters. For example. In computer systems data is transferred from the CPU to/from memory. Bits are transported along parallel pathways thus increasing the data rate.

Comment: There is my confusion, we are talking about sending data, signal. How we are sending it? either electromegnetic for or directly using weird connection. So I am think it as a electricity. is it>?

Comment: @Obiick: You need to be more specific. In computers we use current to send and voltage to indicate (electricity). We can use light, heat, sound, pressure, colour  of smoke. There is no general rule. Your question is too general.

Answer (score 4):

> What are bits in general?

They are *information.*

> Are they electricity?

No.

> When we say bits per second, are we talking about the speed of electricity?

No.

Often, when we want to send a bunch of information, we [*encode* it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code) as a *sequence* of bits,* and then we send the bits, one-by-one, through some channel to another location. The number of bits per second literally is how many of the bits in the sequence we are able to send in each second of real-time.

[* Often there are multiple levels of encoding in a message. We may encode a message as a sequence of English words and punctuation symbols. Each word is represented by a sequence of roman letters. Each letter and symbol is [encoded as a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point), and finally each number is encoded as a sequence of bits.]

> What are they?

Like many words, "bit" has more than one meaning.

Sometimes a "bit" is a [small amount of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) (the equivalent of a "yes" or a "no") that was transmitted from one place to another or, that was recorded in some place.

Sometimes a "bit" is a [*signal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal)—a path through which information "flows"—that can be made to carry one "bit" of information (as described above) at a time.

Sometimes a "bit" is a "binary digit. That is, a "1" or a "0" appearing in the [binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (a.k.a., "base two representation") of some number.

> is there any way to see bits?

Depends on what you mean by "bit." Depends on what you mean by "see." You can literally see binary digits—zeros and ones. Here are a few for you to contemplate:

```
0110 1001 1010 0001
```

You can see other *representations* of single bits of information.

```
yes
no
True
False
Active
Inactive
Enabled
Disabled
Inside
Outside
Home
Away
...
```

Sometimes you can see actual signals. E.g., If I tell you that if I leave the porch light on, then it's OK for you to knock on my door, but if the light is off, I want you to leave me alone. The state of the light is a signal that carries one bit of information, and you can literally see it just by turning your eyes in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

> *When we say bits per second, are we talking about the speed of
> electricity.*

It's not the speed of electricity; that's different. Have you got a WiFi router? If you have you might have noticed that the product claims to be able to transfer data at "so-many" mega bits per second and, that's what it's all about.

One bit per second is one bit of data transferred each second; it's a data transmission rate and not the speed at which data flies through the air or, along cables. Think old-fashioned semaphore signalling between ships or Morse code.

Comment: so when it is sending(on) is there any electricity flowing ?  sorry I am a newbie. Trying to understand stuff

Comment: There isn't electricity flow when sailors use semaphore flags however, data (or information) is transferred. Whether electricity flows or not is irrelevant to what a bit is @Obiick Electricity is the medium in which we choose to transfer lots of data (bits) but, it could be through a vacuum (as in the case of radio) or through water as in the similar situation of sonar pulses.